# JsonConvert - Force MissingMember to null

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-core, json.net

I have a `FilterDto` class I use to send filter information to my client application.
For instance:

```
public class FilterDto
{
    public string Code { get; set; } = "Default code";
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This is serialized like:

```
[
    {
        field: 'Code',
        type: 'text',
        defaultValue: 'Default code'
    },
    {
        field: 'Description ',
        type: 'text',
        defaultValue: null
    }
]
```

So in my client I can render two `input` `text` for the given fields. And when the user filters the JSON sent back is something like:

```
{
    Code: 'code to filter',
    Description: 'description to filter'
}
```

And I desserialize it like:

```
var filter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(FilterDto));
Console.WriteLine(filter.Code); // code to filter
```

The problem is, if the user decides to erase the default value for code, in the above example, I will have the JSON:

```
{
    Description: 'description to filter'
}
```

And when desserializing I will have:

```
var filter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(FilterDto));
Console.WriteLine(filter.Code); // Default code
```

Is there a way to set the `Code` to null instead of its default value when it is missing from the JSON?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        public class FilterDto
        {
            private const string DefaultValue = "Default code";

            [OnDeserialized]
            internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
            {
                if (Code == DefaultValue)
                {
                    Code = null; //set to null or string.empty
                }
            }

            public string Code { get; set; } = DefaultValue;
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: This works but I was expecting something more generic... Without having to write that logic for every `FilterDto` I have... Currently I'm using some reflection to set the values to default if they are not present in the json...

Comment: Have a look into this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908592/add-a-custom-attribute-to-json-net

Answer (score 0):

i believe, what you are looking already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830206/json-convert-empty-string-instead-of-null)

.

in addition, if property is not exists you might add

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName ="defaultValue", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
```

also, this article will give you idea how to cover null value: [here](https://blog.magentaize.net/convert-null-to-empty-collection-when-deserializing-json-using-json-net/)